# How to configure in Google Core IoT?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, configuration, mqtt, iot

I've made a python program in Raspberry Pi 3 Model B that's supposed to connect to Google Cloud IoT Core with MQTT-protocol and get configurations. Sending data to Core has worked so far, but I just can't figure out how configuring works! Here's a code that's just supposed to get a config:

```
    import time
    import datetime
    import jwt
    import ssl
    import json
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


    time_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()


    #make key
    token  = {'iat' : time_now ,
              'exp' : time_now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
              'aud' : "[PROJECT]"}

    r = open("[PRIVATE KEY]", 'r')
    pub_key = r.read()

    jwt_key = jwt.encode(token, pub_key, algorithm='RS256')


    #connect to iot-core
    client = mqtt.Client(client_id='projects/[PROJECT]/locations/[LOCATION]/registries/[REGISTER]/devices/[DEVICE]')
    client.username_pw_set(username='unused', password=jwt_key)

    client.tls_set(ca_certs='/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/_cython/_credentials/roots.pem', tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    client.connect("mqtt.googleapis.com", 8883)

    #configure and change state
    state = 0

    print state #naturally shows 0

    print client.subscribe([DEVICE]/config, qos=1) #doesn't print custom config either, just (0,1) 

    print state #still shows 0
```

configuration in Iot Core device id is:

`{ "state": 1 }`

Even after running the program, the device's "state"-variable stays at 0 and the Core's Configuration & State History state that the CONFIG is "Not yet acknowledged by the device"

How do I get the device's "state" variable change from 0 to 1 from Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done the half of the job. 2 remarks.

1. It's maybe a detail, but you name your private key `pub_key`. And you don't close the file.
2. [Based on this tutorial](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/into-mqtt-python-client/), you only subscribe to the MQTT. The return tuple `(0,1)` means `MQTT_ERR_SUCCESS` on `QOS` = 1. Thus your are connected. Great! Now, do the second part: consume the messages in the channel, and make your logic (according with the received message, change the state in your app if it's your use case)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But for some reason it displays the message twice.